# Rails scopes for even and odd record IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site where the client wants records displayed in two columns. I created a couple of scopes and on the page set one column to return odd records and the other to return even records.

#### These are my scopes:

`scope :odd, -> { where("id % 2 = ?", "0") }`

`scope :even, -> { where("id % 2 = ?", "1") }`

Appears to be working but: a) is this proper/safe syntax?  b) Is there a simpler way to select odd and even ID numbers?

Comment: the odd and even words dont reflect the correct scopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a ruby solution is possible, it is more-proper to use CSS.  This is because your feature is mainly a presentation concern.

To further point out the distinction I would ask, *what if the client comes back and wants a four-column display?*

---

**To achieve a display like the following**

```
record 1 | record 2
record 3 | record 4
record 5 | record 6
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="double">
  <li>CSS</li>
  <li>XHTML</li>
  <li>Semantics</li>
  <li>Accessibility</li>
  <li>Usability</li>
  <li>Web Standards</li>
  <li>PHP</li>
  <li>Typography</li>
  <li>Grids</li>
  <li>CSS3</li>
  <li>HTML5</li>
  <li>UI</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
  width:600px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
li{
  line-height:1.5em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
#double li  { width:50%;}       /* 2 col */
#triple li  { width:33.333%; }  /* 3 col */
#quad li    { width:25%; }      /* 4 col */
#six li     { width:16.666%; }  /* 6 col */
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KnXEc/

More: http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is an interesting solution. I am using Zurb Foundation, so wonder how this would work when the responsive design kicks in. I bookmarked the article you reference.

Comment: A CSS media query could be used to switch at the same time as the other Foundation objects. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

If getting records by odd and even ids is really what you want to do, then your solution is fine.  AFAIK there isn't a shortcut for it, because it isn't often done.

One thing you should consider is that the columns may become unbalanced once you start deleting records.  That might not be a concern for you, though.

Comment: You are dead on correct about the columns getting out of balance due to removing, adding records.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are displaying all records anyway, you could use [`Enumerable#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
@even_ids, @odd_ids = Record.all.partition { |r| r.id.even? }
```

Comment: I'll have to test this out. Thanks for the tip.